# Old mecha anime with white winged aliens

Tags: tosho-daimos

I have vague memory of an old (maybe 70's or 80's, it is very old) mecha anime TV show or movie that involved winged aliens and one scene in particular where the main guy is with an alien girl in a field of flowers and when the wind blows the flowers change colors. There was some robot martial arts action, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually revisited this several years ago because I remember the scene with the flowers. The show is called [Tosho Daimos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C5%8Dsh%C5%8D_Daimos), or "Star Birds" in the English localization.

> It is earth's most desperate hour. It is a time for heroes. And it is the ultimate battle for freedom in this rocket-fueled animated spectacular!
>
> The Starbirds have invaded planet Earth. It seems our only hope lies with Kelly- a daring young starfighter who pilots an indestructible cyborg robot. But wait! A growing force of Starbird rebels are fighting to overthrow the oppressive rule of their King Oban. And together with Kelly, they join forces to rid the galaxy of King Oban's treacherous rein so that the Starbirds and the people of Earth may one day be free.

I haven't seen the entirety of the TV series, which is 44 episodes, but I've seen an edited version of the TV series released as a movie on VHS that's dubbed in English. I'm not sure if this is the same thing as what Anime News Network lists as the "[Tosho Daimos movie](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=3991)".

The scene with the flowers occurs in the movie around 30 minutes in:

[image]
The petals are pink on top and yellow underneath, as the kid pointed out.

[image]
"Kelly" and "Erica" in a field of flowers.